# How can I use a buffer as image (without writing it as a file and read again)

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

```
  buffer = canvas.toBuffer("image/jpeg");
  await fs.writeFileSync(id + ".jpeg", buffer);
  (async() => {
    var { media } = await client.uploadPhoto({
      photo: id + ".jpeg",
      caption: "",
      post: "feed"
    });
    console.log(`https://www.instagram.com/p/${media.code}/`);
  })();
```

First I create a buffer to write a file.
Then I write it to the current path with the name of id. In the async function, I try to get a photo as id+"jpeg". However, I don't want to do that because I run it on a server. Servers do not have storages. So it gives an error. I need something like

```
...client.uploadPhoto({
          photo: buffer.toImage(),
          caption: "",
          post: "feed"
        });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance...
The API that I use is [this](https://github.com/jlobos/instagram-web-api)

Comment: What is `client`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder client is about the instagram API that I used. Think like client is your account and you upload a photo to your account

Comment: Please tag or link the relevant API. The only valid answers I can see would need to cite another upload mechanism supported by the API.

Comment: The issue is not about the API. I just should not use fs.writeFileSync(), because I cannot. I need something else to pass as argument to {photo: ....} so that I don't read any path like => "/" + id + ".jpeg"

Comment: T.J.Crowder is right, if `client.uploadPhoto` only supports an upload from local filesystem (`photo` is a path to a file), there is no other way. However if `client.uploadPhoto` has other options or supports other values for `photo`, they might be used instead.

Comment: @Vitalii Ohh, I get it now. You are saying that {photo} needs a path, I can only use a path. The API I am using is [this](https://github.com/jlobos/instagram-web-api) . I will search for if there is another way to upload a photo

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think {photo} needs a path as string. I think the best way is to upload the buffer to storage then I can pass the url as argument.

Comment: The library seems to [only support](https://github.com/jlobos/instagram-web-api/blob/e85a0f603e5be9e147606feed73a5057d74c5c60/lib/index.js#L370-L375) an URL or a filesystem path as `photo` param. Instead of local file you can upload to any [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network#Notable_content_delivery_service_providers) and pass the resulting image URL to the library.